# How to control verbose logs in user builds?

Tags: android

I can see LOGV message is USER builds (in logcat).

On user builds typically verbose logging is disabled ? or at least that is what I thought.
how we could ensure that our LOGV messages show up in userdebug but not on user builds ?

Thanks
Himanshu

Answer (score 0):

Build your own Log class that detects if its a debug build or not, and then use that for all your Logs.

Have a look at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html

it might look something like this:

```
public void logv(String tag, String message) {

        if(isDebug()) {
            Log.v(tag,message);
        }

        private boolean isDebug() {
            return (0 != (myContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.myapp",0).applicationInfo.flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE)); 
        }
    }
}
```

Or use Log.d instead of Log.v